# linux files and folders are not inheriting parent directory permissions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, chmod

I created a directory `/share` and gave `chmod 2770` permission and `chown root:stock /share`.

1) When I create touch a file inside `/share`, I see the file has `rw-rw-r--` and I don't see `rwxrws---`

2) When I create a directory in `/share/data` I see the permission as `drwxrwsr-x` where are the parent directory is `drwxrws---`

How can I get parent child files and child directories to inherent parent permissions exactly the same.

Comment: See [What's the purpose of setgid directory?](http://serverfault.com/questions/93894/whats-the-purpose-of-setgid-directory)

Comment: Please explain a little about the problem you're trying to solve. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a file or directory

- The owner of the new file or directory will be your effective user id (`euid`). You can change user id beforehand with the `su other_user` command (which will prompt you for the password of `other_user`), or `sudo su other_user` (which will allow you or not, possibly asking for your password, according to the settings in `/etc/sudoers*`). After creating the file or directory, you can change its owner with `sudo chown other_user file_name`.
- The group of the new file or directory will be your effective group id. You can change your group id with the `newgrp other_group` command beforehand. If your current directory has `other_group` as group and its `setgid` bit is set, your effective group id will be `other_group`. After creating the file or directory, you can change its group with `chgrp other_group file_name`.  `newgrp`, `chgrp` and `setgid` will work if you are a member of `other_group`. If you are not, they won’t: a group password mechanism is theoretically still in place, but it was deprecated decades ago and I’ve never seen anybody using it. Of course, you can always `sudo chgrp other_group file_name`, or even `sudo chown other_user:other_group file_name` if you want to change both.
- The read and write permissions of the new file or directory will depend on your `umask`, which is normally set by your configuration files at login. The most used umask values are `022` which, for files, will give you `-rw-r--r--` and `002` which will give you `-rw-rw-r--`. The command `umask` will give you your current value. You can set another value with `umask new_value` and it will be effective till you change it or exit your shell. Directories will have also all execution permissions set by default, unless you have odd values in `umask`, which will block the corresponding execution bit. E.g. a umask value of `027` will create files with `-rw-r-----` and directories with `drwxrwx---`. Please refer to documentation for a complete explanation. Also, if the parent directory has the `setgid` bit, the new directory will have it too. There is no way of setting the `setuid` and `sticky` bits by default, nor the `setgid` bit for files.
- After the fact, you can always set the permissions you want with the command `chmod`.

That said, there is no standard command which will do what you want. However, you can easily write bash functions like the following and use them (write them in a file `mycreat_functions` and `source mycreat_functions` when needed). This will do for manually created files and directories. For file created by programs, shell redirections and the like, you will still have to correct the permissions manually.

```
function mymkdir () {
  local parentperms
  for a in "$@"; do

    mkdir "$a"

    # This copies all permissions of the parent,
    # exactly as they are
    parentperms="$(stat -c%a $(dirname "$a"))"
    chmod "$parentperms" "$a"

    # if I’m root...
    if [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
      chown "$(stat -c%u:%g "$a")" "$a"
    fi

  done
}


function mytouch () {
  local parentperms newperms
  for a in "$@"; do

    touch "$a"

    # This inherits all permissions of the parent,
    # but removes the excution and setgid bits, as is 
    # appropriate for files.
    parentperms="$(stat -c%a $(dirname "$a"))"
    newperms="$(printf %o $((8#$parentperms & 8#5666)))"
    chmod "$newperms" "$a"

    # if I’m root...
    if [ $(id -u) = 0 ]; then
      chown "$(stat -c%u:%g "$a")" "$a"
    fi

  done
}
```

***Note:*** Owner, group and permissions are stored in an *inode,* where there is also other information on how to retrieve the file contents; the *directory entry* associates the inode with the file name, and `ls -i` shows the *inode numbers* of the listed files. When you *copy* a file, you create a new directory entry and allocate a new inode, so everything mentioned here applies. When you *move* a file, you create a new directory entry in the new location, but have it point to the old inode, so that owner, group and permissions are effectively untouched. If you want them to change according to the new directory entry’s parent, you have to create a `mymv` function along the lines of `mytouch` and `mymkdir` above.

Comment: Well, when sgid is set on dir1 and I am copying from outside to dir1 i get same group as dir1 which is expected but when I move the file from outside to dir1 then the group of moved file is not as dir1?

Comment: Thanks Dario, Well mentioned... I got my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `setgid` bit on a directory makes new files inherit the `group` from the directory, not its permissions.

The standard way of controlling the bits that get set on the creation of a file is to control the [umask](https://askubuntu.com/a/44548/99788) (askubuntu) of the creating process, not the file system.

Comment: Is there any way I can Inherit the parent permissions?

Comment: Not from the directory, but if all files are created by the same process, you could set umask (link included in the answer).

Comment: Well, when sgid is set on dir1 and I am copying from outside to dir1 i get same group as dir1 which is expected but when I move the file from outside to dir1 then the group of moved file is not as dir1?

Comment: Thanks Henk. I like you answer its short and simple.